# Twitter Bootstrap datetimepicker days vertical - LESS Import?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK4OB.png

Currently my display is like this.

I have a master page which I am using to import my css and js.

```
<link href="assets/css/datepicker.css" rel=Stylesheet />
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel=Stylesheet />
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel=Stylesheet />
<link href="assets/css/docs.css" rel=Stylesheet />
<link href="assets/less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet/less" />
```

In head and for the javascript:

```
<script src="assets/js/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script>
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

The control:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012"
data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span> </div>
```

Want the days to go horizontal as they should be, not sure what i'm missing?

Comment: Honestly... pretend you're somebody else trying to answer this question. How far would you get? What is the question anyway... I don't see one other than "less important?". What does that mean?

Comment: Well, if you view the image in the URL you can clearly see that the days are going vertically as appose to horizontally. LESS is the CSS for twitter bootstrap and it says Import? As I think that is probably what is happening.

The CSS in the question, shows what I have done to get to the problem - what is there to not understand?

Comment: Do you want only the .less css of bootstrap datepicker to use it in your masterpage?You can check that with firebug and see that.Along with that check you have any table properties other than in bootstrap.

Comment: I am putting it in the master so that I can use it with other pages. What exactly do I need to look for?

Comment: If you post a direct link to what you're working will be easy or can you make a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you need **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/MDUZq/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>​
```

**Script:**

```
$('#dp3').datepicker();
var startDate = new Date(2012,1,20);
var endDate = new Date(2012,1,25);​
```

Comment: I have this, the problem is the picture - I have the .css which you have in the resources at the appropriate link however I the days are going verticaly as apose to horizontaly - I don't know if that is down to somthing that I am missing?